# Posting checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, mustache

I have a set of checkboxes on my web page. On Save, I serialize and POST the form.

```
<div>
<label for="ViewAsWebpage">
{{#if this.ViewAsWebpage}}
   <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage" value="true"/> 
   <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" checked /> 
{{else}}
   <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage"  value="false"/> 
   <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox"  /> 
{{/if}}
<span>View as Webpage</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Using the above code:

- on GET - the checkboxes are checked/unchecked based on the property
  ViewAsWebpage
- on POST - whatever the user selects should be posted.

But when I POST, it is not sending the correct values. Can someone pls suggest the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<input type="checkbox">` elements are missing `name` attributes, so they won't correspond to request parameters when you post the form.

Comment: Thanks. Should I also remove the value="true" from the hidden tags?

Comment: @dotNetNewbie Having `<input type="hidden">` form elements that correspond to the same request parameters as the checkboxes may be entirely redundant, unless you're planning on disabling the checkbox elements. There shouldn't be any negative effects from leaving them exactly as they are though.

Comment: I added the name attribute as you suggested. Using Firebug for testing- if unchecked: ViewAsWebpage="", but when checked, I get an array IsViewAsWebpage=["", "on"]. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you aren't using the **name** property.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" name="key_in_post" />
```

Using that you should see it in the POST data as, in this case, key_in_post with the value "on" if it was checked.